# Applying CQRS to Legacy DB where data integrity is not guaranteed?

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design, cqrs

We can’t migrate from the Legacy DB at the moment, so we put it behind repository and working on Domain part. The same DB will be used for Read and Write parts and we don’t use Event Sourcing too.

My dilemma is what if current data is invalid as it didn’t go through domain logic at first place? So, there is a chance we can send inconsistent data to client with `ReadModels` which is not acceptable in our case. A few ideas:

- Add some validation step to make sure that all data is processed through WriteModels at least once before it can use it.
- Add some validation to ReadModels? (Would lead to code duplication).
- Use Write Models to query data? (Would break CQRS idea).
- Do not use CQRS and stick with DDD where read results will be constructed from domain invariants that will make sure we do not pass to client any un-consistent data. Thanks!

Comment: What would you do if your model let wrong data slip through somehow? You either discard the data, sanitize it (automatically or manually -- e.g. as a business process where wrong data would be marked for correction) or accept that data as is which becomes a new reality of your domain and must be supported. I do not see any other option.

Comment: @plalx: hard to say how big risk of user not realizing that data is wrong and making wrong decisions that may lead to patient death (even simple delay is a risk)? In Medical device nothing wrong can slip to client side. I'm thinking to have data validation step before opening system to users. Also, separate question, but maybe you know, how in CQRS is handled something like blood product expiration? Again on read side there is no logic, but user must be aware about it right away.

Comment: Or share domain invariants between Write and Read parts. And fix this after we finally will get migrated from Legacy DB. 50/50 for me right now.

Comment: You already have a read and write model right? If yes, then just write a "migration" tool, which will read your write model and on it validate it, then generate your read models from the write model and write it to the read store. Basically, dump the read model and regenerate it and during that process mark the broken/invalid models (i.e. write them into another database). Now that you which are broken, fix them (if auto fixing isn't possible), repeat the process

Comment: Best on it, you don't even have to throw out your code, with read/write models you will always end up with the possibility of inconsistent state and by regenerating bring it on latest state

Comment: @Tseng: It all started from domain invariants in classic DDD. But I liked how CQRS handles updates through events and it fits very well auditing requirements. So I applied that to couple domainsmodels. I already have reading part generated from domain invariants and I technically can leave it as it. But I thought, if I kinda use writing CQRS way I could simplify reading part. Reading and Writing parts go to the same legacy DB that I can't change much. So reading is generated from the same tables and in migration tool it will be enough just to read write models and remember log what failed.

Answer (score 0):

> My dilemma is what if current data is invalid as it didn’t go through domain logic at first place?

The good news: the answer here doesn't really depend on whether you are working with a legacy database, a simple CQRS approach, or full metal event sourcing.

> Add some validation to ReadModels? (Would lead to code duplication).

This is the right answer.

The duplication, I think you'll find, is an illusion.

Key ideas: first, the decision not to share inconsistent data is local to the read model.  Your code should be written in such a way that you can change that decision in the read model *without affecting the write model* in any way.

[On the Criteria to be Used in Decoupling Systems into Modules](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Design/criteria.pdf), by Parnas, is a good starting point.

Second: the read model and the write model have the concept of *state* in common.  That's the stuff that's stored in your database, getting expressed as values in your model.  There's no reason that the read model and the write model can't share an implementation for validating state.

Comment: I don't get why you would want to solve this on the read side. Data integrity is the job of the write side and deciding how to deal with integrity issues should be the job of the write side as well in my mind. If data should not be presented to clients because it is invalid then it should be marked as such from the write side and the read models would react accordingly, no? Writing logic in the read side of things to detect inconsistent data seems very odd to me.

Comment: Not quite: the job of the write model is _change management_.  You go to war with the data you have, not the data you wish you had.

Comment: So you are saying that if your write model is wrong and let bad data through then it's up to the read model to make up for it? I'd be way more confident issuing compensating actions in the write side.